# What is the meaning of highlighted part in the paragraph given down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

“But there is another group of observable phenomena, more subtle, that you can't study in fact, you can't even tell they're there at all **unless you suspend or bracket your skepticism** and try every way possible to perceive them.”

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suspend your scepticism means to pause or temporarily prevent this quality from being in force.

To bracket your scepticism means to restrain it, check it; don't allow it to be active.

He needs to do one or the other (or both) if he is expected to understand whatever esoteric mumbo-jumbo is taking place in this text.

Answer (score 1):

It means you have to believe/have faith in order to be able to see less obvious tangible things
(basically the opposite of a scientific mind)